# Agregar nombre a imagen enviada por smtp python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from getpass import getpass
import smtplib


class Datos():

    def __init__(self,user_in, password, user_out, asunto, mensaje):

        self.user_in = user_in
        self.password = password
        self.user_out = user_out
        self.asunto = asunto
        self.mensaje = mensaje


class Servicio():

    def menu(self):

        user_in = input("\nIntroduce tu correo electronico: ").strip()
        password = getpass("\nIntroduce tu contraseña: ").strip()
        user_out = input("\nIntroduce el correo electronico destino: ").strip()
        asunto = input("\nIntroduce el asunto: ").strip()
        mensaje = input("\nIntroduce un mensaje: ").strip()

        objeto = Datos(user_in,password,user_out,asunto,mensaje)

        try:
            init = Servicio()
            init.send(objeto)

        except:
            print("\nHa ocurrido un error, intentelo de nuevo.")


    def send(self,cliente):

        servidor_smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

        servidor_smtp.ehlo()
        servidor_smtp.starttls()
        servidor_smtp.ehlo()

        try:
            servidor_smtp.login(cliente.user_in,cliente.password)

        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print("\nHa ocurrido un error de autenticacion, intentelo de nuevo.")
            servidor_smtp.quit()

        except:
            print("\nHa ocurrido un error.")
            servidor_smtp.quit()

        else:
            print("\nTe has logueado con exito.")


        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = cliente.user_in
        msg['To'] = cliente.user_out
        msg['Subject'] = cliente.asunto
        msg.attach(MIMEText(cliente.mensaje))

        with open(r"C:\Users\EQUIPO\Desktop\jpg050.jpg",'rb') as image:
            contenido = MIMEImage(image.read())
            contenido.add_header('Content_Disposition','attachment',filename = 'jpg050.jpg')
            msg.attach(contenido)

        try:
            servidor_smtp.sendmail(cliente.user_in,cliente.user_out,msg.as_string())

        except:
            print("\nNo se ha podido enviar el correo correctamente.")
            servidor_smtp.quit()

        else:
            print("\nEl correo se ha enviado con exito.")
            servidor_smtp.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    init = Servicio()
    init.menu()
```

Tengo una pregunta respecto al envió de correos electrónicos por python3.

Básicamente todo me sale bien, solo que al recibir el correo, en especial las imágenes, estas llegan con el siguiente titulo "noname".

Hay alguna forma de cambiar esto por el nombre del archivo en si?

Fíjense de la linea 63 a 72 (enviar imagen a correo electrónico por smtp)

Yo pensaba que el parámetro filename era para que cuando me llegara dicha imagen al correo esta tuviera como nombre de dicha imagen, pero en vez de eso, como lo dije anteriormente, me aparece como "noname"

[image: He aquí el problema, la que dice "noname" es la que envié desde mi script, y el que aparece el nombre de la imagen lo envié desde el mismo gmail]

Comment: provee un [mre]

Comment: Creo que quedo mas que clara la pregunta, agregue codigo e imagen.

Comment: Lo único raro que veo es que has puesto como nombre de cabecera para el adjunto `"Content_Disposition"`, en lugar de `"Content-Disposition"`

Comment: Era ese el error, muchas gracias.